# How can I add a horizontal line in WPF Toolkit Chart?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I have the following chart:

```
    <DVC:Chart x:Name="userChart" Title="Stats" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
      <DVC:Chart.Series>
        <DVC:LineSeries Title="TEST"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserChartList}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                        >
       </DVC:LineSeries>
     </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
```

How can I add a stripline (a parallel line to the x-axis) to my lineseries.

Comment: Look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488433/how-can-i-add-a-horizontal-line-goal-line-for-a-chart-in-wpf/15496070?noredirect=1#comment21950864_15496070

Comment: Your question is answered here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488433/how-can-i-add-a-horizontal-line-goal-line-for-a-chart-in-wpf