# How can I add a horizontal line ("goal line") for a chart in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, customization, wpftoolkit

I'm using the WPF toolkit (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co) to create a line graph.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<Window x:Class="TempDataAnalyzer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
         <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Temperature" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
         </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> entries = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 0));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 23));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2, 45));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3, 46));
        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(4, 71));

        lineChart.DataContext = entries;
    }

}
```

[image]

I need to draw a "goal line" at a specified value of Y, say, in this case - 35:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already do similar things in some of my projects.

I create the line like that :

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chart1" Title="Chart Title">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Polyline">
                <Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="5 5 5" />
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

I use it with the MVVM pattern, and I bind the "LineSeries" with an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I accepted a bit too quick. Your answer styles the datapoints, removes the circles and adds a magenta colour. Look at the last screenshot with the red line. That is what I'm after... leaving the datapoints as they are, not modifying the data in any way and adding a physical line at a set point (ex: Where Y = 35)

Comment: @@David : I just updated my answer. I think now it should solve your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```xml
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">

        <!-- <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/> -->
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Height"  Value="2" />
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Polyline">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries.PolylineStyle>
```